# Upload files with metadata, Azure JAVA API

Tags: java, azure, metadata

I am trying to upload a file with certain `METADATA` to an azure blob container.

When I do it with the .net SDK it simple sends one `put` and all `metadata` as it should be.

However, if I try with Java it sends 3 `puts` and the `metadata` won't be reflected until I issue a `cBlockBlob.uploadProperties()` command, and until the 3rd `put`.

Why is it going through 3 `puts`? is it an issue in the JAVA sdk?

**This is the 1st put**

```
*PUT /mycontainer/0721ef8f-8d70-4b91-9d1f-04757363f903.xml?blockid=AAAAAEm%2FC%2FE%3D& comp=block&sr=c&timeout=4&si=WriteOnly& sig=eUe%2Fe7kcFcmiIzOVNgqbXd%2BjlIN3ZQd8fkQq3IsHQVQ%3D HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
User-Agent: WA-Storage/Client v0.1.1
Content-Type: 
Host: certainhost.blob.core.windows.net
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 4613*
```

**This is the 2nd put**

```
*PUT /mycontainer/0721ef8f-8d70-4b91-9d1f-04757363f903.xml?comp=blocklist&sr=c&timeout=4&si=WriteOnly&sig=eUe%2Fe7kcFcmiIzOVNgqbXd%2BjlIN3ZQd8fkQq3IsHQVQ%3D HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18  
User-Agent: WA-Storage/Client v0.1.1
Content-Type: 
Content-MD5: hYRJFeM5RFH29bPj3oxhwA==
Host: certainhost.blob.core.windows.net
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 100*

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><BlockList><Uncommitted>AAAAAEm/C/E=</Uncommitted></BlockList>
```

**This is the 3rd put (the one that shows required `metadata`)**

```
*PUT /mycontainer/0721ef8f-8d70-4b91-9d1f-04757363f903.xml?comp=properties&sr=c&timeout=4&si=WriteOnly&sig=eUe%2Fe7kcFcmiIzOVNgqbXd%2BjlIN3ZQd8fkQq3IsHQVQ%3D HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2011-08-18
User-Agent: WA-Storage/Client v0.1.1
Content-Type: 
x-ms-blob-content-encoding: utf-8
x-ms-meta-x-ms-meta-versionCFDI: 3.2
Host: certainhost.blob.core.windows.net
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0*
```

**and this is the only put in .net SDK**

```
*PUT /mycontainer/0721ef8f-8d70-4b91-9d1f-04757363f903.xml?comp=properties&sr=c&timeout=4&si=WriteOnly&sig=eUe%2Fe7kcFcmiIzOVNgqbXd%2BjlIN3ZQd8fkQq3IsHQVQ%3D HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
User-Agent: WA-Storage/6.0.6002.18312
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
x-ms-meta-versionCFDI: 3.2
Host: certainhost.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 6841
Connection: Keep-Alive*
```

**Something else, what does this mean?**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><BlockList><Uncommitted>AAAAAEm//E=</Uncommitted></BlockList>
```

It is sent in the second put, .net won't show it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is that JAVA SDK is splitting your file into blocks and uploading those blocks. The first PUT request a "PUT Block" request and the second one is the "Commit Block List" request and the 3rd one is the "Set Metadata" request. Based on the REST API documentation, you can set a blob's metadata during "Commit Block List" operation as well (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179467.aspx). It does seem odd that .Net SDK uploads this file in just one request while Java SDK splits the file in blocks and upload it. I wouldn't be surprised if this is how it is implemented in Java SDK. What's the size of the file which you're trying to upload?

Regarding your 2nd question, that's the payload for "Commit Block List" operation.